# How can I add an effect to wherever I click in Swift

Tags: swift

What I want to do, is whenever the user clicks anywhere on the screen, a shadow or an instance of a shadow is created wherever they click for as long as they click. Like having an app that has a white background but whenever you press the screen a black dot appears under your finger and follows it but when you take your finger off it disappears.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you use SpriteKit?

Answer (score 0):

To handle touch events, here's a great [guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial) on UIGestureRecognizers on Raywenderlich.

As for the black dot that you described, you could try drawing it with CoreGraphics.